# Google Maps API data layer feature. Event dragend not fired

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a data layer:

```
mylayer.loadGeoJson(myGeoJsonString);
mylayer.setStyle(function(feature){
    var col = feature.getProperty('strokeColor');
    return  { strokeColor: col,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        clickable: true,
        draggable: true             
    }
});
```

Every feature can be moved on the map with a drag operation with mouse, but if I try to add a listener to the dragend event:

```
    mylayer.addListener('dragend', function(event) {
        if (confirm("Do you really want to move it?")) {
            console.log ("Moved, need to update spatial DB...");
        }
    });
```

But event does not fire (checked with a Google Chrome Debug Console breakpoint too).

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `dragend` event on the [Google Maps Javascript API Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer)

See this answer for available events: [What events are available for google.maps.data.addListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202702/what-events-are-available-for-google-maps-data-addlistener) or the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data)

**Available Events:**

> - addfeature
> - click
> - mousedown
> - mouseout
> - mouseover
> - mouseup
> - removefeature
> - removeproperty
> - rightclicksetgeometry
> - setproperty

Comment: Thanks, do you know any good practice using mousedown and mouseup events to detect a drag end?

Comment: The mousedown and mouseup events have the feature as part of the event object. So you can store the ID of the object on the side as mousedown is fired. When mouseup fires you can see if the if the ID matches AND if the geometry is different. If the geometry is different you know it was a drag event and not just a click. You could also check for a minimum amount of change in geometry to avoid accidental minor drags and overeager clicking.

Answer (score 0):

When you make calls to the Data Layer API, you can receive the status of the call when it completes as well as listen for any changes that the call ends up making with listeners.

You'll notice that calls to the Data Layer API sometimes return a '*PendingResult*'. As soon as the '*PendingResult*' is created, the operation is queued in the background, so the *PendingResult* lets you wait for the result status, either *synchronously* or *asynchronously*.

If your code is running on the main UI thread, do not make blocking calls to the Data LayerAPI. You can run the calls asynchronously by adding a callback method to the *PendingResult*.

If your code is running on a separate handler thread in a background service, its fine for the calls to block. In this case, you can call "*await*()' on the PendingResult.

For more information regarding Event handling, please follw this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-event