# What events are available for google.maps.data.addListener?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I'm using:

```
mydatalayer.addListener('click', function(event) { ... });
mydatalayer.addListener('addfeature', function(event) { ... });
```

without problems.

Now I'm trying to use:

```
mydatalayer.addListener('dragend', function(event) { ... });
```

but event listener is not fired, although the selected polygon on that layer is correctly dragged on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events available on a [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) are listed in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data)

> **Events**
>
> - **addfeature** | Arguments:  Data.AddFeatureEvent -
>   This event is fired when a feature is added to the collection.
> - **click** | Arguments:  Data.MouseEvent -
>   This event is fired for a click on the geometry.
> - **dblclick** | Arguments:  Data.MouseEvent -
>   This event is fired for a double click on the geometry.
> - **mousedown** | Arguments:  Data.MouseEvent-
>   This event is fired for a mousedown on the geometry.
> - **mouseout** | Arguments:  Data.MouseEvent -
>   This event is fired when the mouse leaves the area of the geometry.
> - **mouseover** | Arguments:  Data.MouseEvent -
>   This event is fired when the mouse enters the area of the geometry.
> - **mouseup** | Arguments:  Data.MouseEvent -
>   This event is fired for a mouseup on the geometry.
> - **removefeature** | Arguments:  Data.RemoveFeatureEvent -
>   This event is fired when a feature is removed from the collection.
> - **removeproperty** | Arguments:  Data.RemovePropertyEvent -
>   This event is fired when a feature's property is removed.
> - **rightclick** | Arguments:  Data.MouseEvent -
>   This event is fired for a rightclick on the geometry.
> - **setgeometry** | Arguments:  Data.SetGeometryEvent -
>   This event is fired when a feature's geometry is set.
> - **setproperty** | Arguments:  Data.SetPropertyEvent -
>   This event is fired when a feature's property is set.

As you can see, `dragend` is not listed at the current time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still making confusion between google.maps.data and google.maps.Polygon, Marker, Polilines